# VSCode: `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` > `comment` does not color the whole comment

Tags: themes, visual-studio-code

#### Environment

- Visual Studio Code *1.18.0* for macOS.
- Theme `hedinne.popping-and-locking-vscode` by **hedinne**.

#### Question

Why is it that the color of the initial `/*` of the block comment is not changed when I override `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` > `comment`?

#### Example

[image: First line of block comment not changed]

Comment: `Developer: Inspect TM Scopes` command from command palette in help

Comment: Did the answer by Alex fix the issue?  I cannot reproduce the error.  SO maybe something about your theme isn't properly capturing all of block comments?

Comment: Yes, Alex's answer is correct! Thanks!

The middle of the comment have the hierarchy `comment.block.documentation.js` > `source.js`.

The start and end of the comment have the hierarchy `punctuation.definition.comment.js` > `comment.block.documentation.js` > `source.js`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.comment",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#33f"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what key to set font size?

Comment: `font-size` is not supported.

Comment: Such a pity. SourceInsight does it well and Netbeans also supports it -- to make larger size and bold/italic function/class declarations and makes them easy to be caught at a glance.  Also, in vscode, if I set `fontStyle` of `entity.name.function` to `bold` in the Monokia theme, it affects not only the function declarations but also the function calls which absolutely not what anyone wants.